# Achieving flatMap effect without using flatMap

Tags: java, java-stream

I have this class which defines a developer.

```
class Developer {
    private final String name;
    Set<String> skills = new HashSet<>();

    public Developer(final String name, final String... skills) {
        this.name = name;
        for (final String skill : skills) {
            this.skills.add(skill);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm creating a list of developers.

```
List<Developer> developers = new ArrayList<>();
people.add(new Developer("Bill", "Javascript", "HTML", "CSS"));
people.add(new Developer("Bob", "Java", "OOP", "Agile"));
people.add(new Developer("Barry", "Data Mining", "Machine Learning", "R"));
```

Now I want to extract a set of the collective skills. I do this using `flatMap` like so:

```
 Set<String> skills = developers.stream().flatMap(dev -> dev.skills.stream()).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Is there any way to do this through `Stream`s without using `flatMap`?

Comment: Why don't you want to use `flatMap`? That's the right method to use.

Comment: @JohnKugelman Im just trying to better understand the difference between map and flatMap and I think the answer to this question will help me better understand.

Answer (score 6):

#### Edit

There is no need to use a thread safe structure inside the collector, since [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.stream.Collector-) says:

> When executed in parallel, multiple intermediate results may be instantiated, populated, and merged so as to maintain isolation of mutable data structures. Therefore, even when executed in parallel with non-thread-safe data structures (such as ArrayList), no additional synchronization is needed for a parallel reduction.

---

`flatMap` is the way to go. It would be nice to know the motivation behind your question.

Another way to achieve the same result would be using [collectors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html) (as stated on other answer).
You could also avoid the `map` and put all in the collector like:

```
Set<String> skills = developers.stream()
    .collect(
        HashSet<String>::new, 
        (acum, dev) -> acum.addAll(dev.skills), 
        Set::addAll
    );
```

Comment: good catch! I modified mi solution with a `ConcurrentSkipListSet`

Comment: @JohnKugelman please look at my edit. There is no need for a thread safe structure there.

Answer (score 3):

You can use overloaded version of `Collectors.collect` which takes arguments `supplier`, `accumulator` and `combiner`

```
Set<String> skills = developers.stream().map(Developer::getSkills)
                               .collect(HashSet::new, Set::addAll, Set::addAll);
System.out.println("Skills :: " + skills);
```

output

```
Skills :: [Java, OOP, CSS, R, Javascript, Agile, Data Mining, HTML, Machine Learning]
```

Comment: @John I didn't maintain any state, why is not safe? Could you explain

Comment: Do I need to use concurrent collection?

Comment: There is no need for a thread-safe structure there since the [collect takes care of isolation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.stream.Collector-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `reduce` like this.

```
Set<String> set = people.stream()
    .map(d -> d.skills)
    .reduce(new HashSet<String>(),
        (map, list) -> { map.addAll(list); return map; });
```

Comment: Also, it would generate a new `HashSet` for each item on the set. I wouldn't mind this on haskell, but it's something to have in account on java.

Comment: @Logaln In this issue, there is no advantage to parallelize.